# Oracle stored procedure hanging when called via jdbc

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, jboss, cursor

I have a web application which executes oracle stored procedures and shows the results on a browser.
The technology stack is as follows: Browser <-> spring mvc <-> [(tomcat)jboss] <-jdbc-> oracle.
The stored procedures have an out cursor for the results and the java code uses that cursor to retrieve the resultset.

Everything was running fine until a new stored procedure was added, which although terminates fast enough in SQL Developer, it freezes when it gets called from the application. The java debugging showed that the code freezes at the OracleCallableStatement.execute. Initially I thought there was something wrong with the procedure but it does run successfully on sql developer, so I am now pointing more towards a jdbc problem...

I guess this has to do with some sort of deadlock while reading the out cursor, or could it be a bug in the jdbc driver (version I am using: ojdbc6 - 11.1.0.7.0)?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure code and the calling JDBC code ?

Comment: I can give you a hint of the code;

Comment: Unfortunately I can't print the code, but can describe it. The stored procedure is very complex and unefficient. However it does terminate in sql developer relatively fast;                PROCEDURE stored_procedure(v_cur OUT sys_refcursor)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN v_cur for
WITH first_temp_table AS
(
SELECT    
FROM
  <inner joins but also many cartesian products>  
WHERE
),
second_temp_table AS
(
SELECT 
FROM
   <inner joins but also many cartesian products>
WHERE 
  <subqueries using the first_temp_table>
)  <Final query selecting on the temp tables, with very complex, unefficient selections and joins>

Comment: Java:I have an XA oracle datasource and I get the connection with; wconn = (WrappedConnection) dataSource.getConnection();Connection conn = (Connection) wconn.getUnderlyingConnection(); The reason for the casting is jboss's connection wrapping which caused a classcast exception when I try to get the OracleResultset later on. The reason for not getting a plain ResultSet is the need for the cursor api.
This is how I get my resultset : stmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(sprocCall.toString());  
resultSet = (OracleResultSet)stmt.getCursor(reportRequest.getCursorPositions().get(0));

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there's no row lock that your session is waiting on. The following SQL*Plus script could give you hints about how to do that. Or have a look in Oracle Enterprise manager (the Oracle web GUI) under Blocking Sessions.

BTW a deadlock is something different that the database would take care of by killing one of the two sessions...

```
REM  Purpose
REM  -------
REM  Display locks currently held and requested. Displays which session a
REM  blocked lock is waiting for.
REM
REM  Ver  Who  When       What
REM  ---  ---  ----       ----
REM  1.0  DrB  12-Dec-97  Initial version
col uname     head "Username"  form a12
col sid       head "SID"       form 999
col ltype     head "Type"      form a4
col lmode     head "Mode"      form a10
col blocked   head "Wait"      form a4
col details   head "Details"   form a40
set verify off
set pause on
accept user prompt  "Username [%]: "
select SubStr('alter system kill session ''' || s.sid || ',' || s.serial# || ''';', 1, 40) as kill, s.username uname, 'DML' ltype,
  decode (l.lmode,1,'Null',
                  2,'Row-S',
                  3,'Row-X',
                  4,'Share',
                  5,'S/Row-X',
                  6,'Exclusive') lmode,
  decode (l.request,0,'No','Yes') blocked,
  u.username||'.'||o.name details,
  Nvl(s.Program, s.Module) What
from v$session s, v$lock l, sys.obj$ o, all_users u
where s.username like nvl(upper('&user'||'%'),'%')
and s.sid = l.sid
and l.id1 = o.obj#
--and l.type = 'TM'
and o.owner# = u.user_id(+)
union all
select SubStr('alter system kill session ''' || s.sid || ',' || s.serial# || ''';', 1, 40) as kill, s.username uname,
  decode (l.type,'TX','TX',
                 'UL','USR',
                      'SYS') ltype,
  decode (l.lmode,1,'Null',
                  2,'Row-S',
                  3,'Row-X',
                  4,'Share',
                  5,'S/Row-X',
                  6,'Exclusive') lmode,
  decode (l.request,0,'No','Yes') blocked,
  decode (l.request,0,null,'Waiting on session '||to_char(b.sid)) details,
  Nvl(s.Program, s.Module) What
from v$session s, v$lock l, v$lock b
where s.username like nvl(upper('&user'||'%'),'%')
and s.sid = l.sid
and l.type != 'TM'
and l.id1 = b.id1(+)
and b.request(+) = 0
order by 5 desc,3 desc,2,1;
set verify on
REM  End of file
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Looking at the oracle web gui while the call was hanging I saw that there were two identical queries blocking each other. I should also mention that this happens only when jboss runs in unix while it works fine on windows. I tried using the latest driver 11.2.0.2.0 but nothing changed.

Comment: Also I am using an oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource

Answer (score 0):

Cool. I reproduced the setup (but did not get a freeze), so this is still a work in progress.

I am fairly certain that the issue is related to the XA transaction in Java since that is the significant difference between executing the stored proc from Java and from SQLDeveloper. Since the call freezes (indefinitely ?), can you reproduce and scoot into JMXConsole and swipe a thread dump from the **jboss.system:type=ServerInfo** MBean ? Seeing a full stack trace will give a better idea of what the thread is waiting on.

==== Addendum ====

Are there any pragmas, DDL or any other transaction affecting clauses in the stored procedure or any of it's dependencies ?

==== Update ====

The thread is runnable so we know the client is simply waiting on a response from the server. I thought about the DDL potentially affecting the Transaction, but based on your pseudo-code, the temporary tables are all created implicitly using the **WITH** statement, which I verified does not trigger a commit. Can you confirm that there are no **CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE** statements ?

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Here is the particular thread's stacktrace from the thread dump:

Comment: Thread: .... priority:5, demon:true, threadId:121, threadState:RUNNABLE
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:240)
oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:92)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:172)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:117)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:77) oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1034)

Comment: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1010)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:588)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:191)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:950)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3488)

Comment: - locked <0x1ba4d7> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:3857)
- locked <0x1ba4d7> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
com.jpm.ibt.primegps.webreports.dao.WebReportsDaoImpl.generateReport(WebReportsDaoImpl.java:112)
com.jpm.ibt.primegps.webreports.services.WebReportsServiceImpl.generateReport(WebReportsServiceImpl.java:93)

Comment: com.jpm.ibt.primegps.webreports.controllers.GenerateReportController.handle(GenerateReportController.java:41)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractCommandController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractCommandController.java:84)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

Comment: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

Comment: org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

Comment: org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: YES the call freezes indefinitely. No there are no DDL or any transactional statements, unless ofcourse the temp table creation is considered a sort of ddl - transactional statement.

Comment: Yes there I can confirm that.